# C++ abstract methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, abstract

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```
class IMyClass1
{
public:
    virtual void method1() = 0;
};

class MyClass1 : public IMyClass1
{
public:
    inline virtual void method1() { /* some code */ }
};

class IMyClass2 : public IMyClass1
{
public:
    virtual void method2() = 0;
};

class MyClass2 : public MyClass1, public IMyClass2
{
public:
    inline virtual void method2() { /* some code */ }
};

void main()
{
    IMyClass2* class2 = new MyClass2();
    class2->method1();
    class2->method2();
    for (;;);
}
```

But when I try to create a new istance of MyClass2 it says it's abstract because of method1 which says is not implemented. However I do want to inherit the implementation from MyClass1. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You need to add the `virtual` keyword to `MyClass1::method1` and to `MyClass2::method2` I think.

Comment: I'm slightly puzzled because the title of your question mentions virtual inheritance but you are actually not using it. Although it could be used to make this work. Both MyClass1 and IMyClass2 need to virtually inherit from IMyClass1. Have a look at the mixin pattern which is what you want to do actually is. Personally I would be very careful with virtual inheritance. Often the little amount of typing you save isn't worth the extra complexity. –  Xavier Leclercq

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the virtual keyword in your MyClass1 method1() declaration. The compiler doesn't see the function as overriding the IMyClass1, so it treats MyClass1 as being pure virtual because it doesn't define the method1() method.

Every method that you intend to override using virtual dispatch must have the virtual keyword associated with its function prototype.

Edit: As noted in someone else's comment, you're also not inheriting from the IMyClass1 class with MyClass1.

Comment: I added the virtual keyword to both methods but it seems not working. I've updated the code, am I missing anything else?